# Erase Google two-factor authentication token

Tags: google, authentication, multi-factor-auth

I logged in to GMail with two-factor authentication and mistakenly left the "Remember this computer for 30 days" option checked.

I'd like to erase the authentication token, so on the next log in it'll still prompt for the temporary code, not just for the password.

Can this be done in other ways than deleting cookies?

Comment: I found the solution and edited my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found it:

When you visit you Google Account Settings, you can select Security in the sidebar menu.

It will list 2-factor authentication. Click the edit button next to it.

This will lead you to this page: https://accounts.google.com/b/0/SmsAuthConfig

At the bottom of the page there would be a section about Trusted Computers. It will say that the computer you currently uses is a trusted computer.

You have the option to either `Remove it from your list of trusted computers` or `Forget all other trusted computers`.

Comment: Found it, edited the answer.

Comment: Nice find. Tested and works great. I especially like the "Forget all other trusted computers" option.